# Sql query did not return all values when using between clause

Tags: sql

I have a query :

```
select *
from indicatordetails
where indicator.month between 'January'and 'April'
```

When I run it it returns no result, but when I use:

```
select *
from indicatordetails
where indicator.month between 'January'and 'march'
```

It returns result.

Note: my table have results starting from January to April, I will appreciate any help, thanks

Comment: You're comparing strings, not months. 'January' > 'April'.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please [add a tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have as a "month" is a string.  The operands for `between` are ordered.  And as strings, `'January'` is after `'April'`.

This is more easily seen with numbers.  This construct:

```
where x between 9 and 1
```

will never return any results, because 9 > 1.  This might return results if there are matching values:

```
where x between 1 and 9
```

My recommendation is to only use this column with `in` or `=`:

```
where indicator.month in ('January', 'February', 'March', 'April')
```

Comment: gordon, thanks ,I intend using this : select * from indicatordetails where indicator.month between month1 and  month2, if am to use in OR =,how will the query be written? (please take note of the parameters @ for month1 and month2)

Comment: Thanks all... From your suggestions, What I did to solve it was to change the type of month from varchar to int so I could use the 'between' clause